# How to get the product version from a Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

I am trying to display my product version in a Razor view (`_Layout.cshtml`). I´m doing something like this:

```
<script>
alert('@FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ProductVersion');
alert('@Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location');
</script>
```

The problem is that the first alert showed me 0.0.0.0 then, I introduced the second alert and it shows me the following location:

> C:WindowsMicrosoft.NETFramework644.0.30319Temporary ASP.NET Filesoot#35f35b93778aeaApp_Web_ztow0zpu.dll

Obviously this is not my assembly file. Is there any easy and clean way to get the assembly version from a Razor view?

Comment: The assembly version and the product version are not the same thing. The assembly version is specified using `AssemblyVersion` attribute. The _product_ version is specified using the `AssemblyInfoVersion` attribute. The accepted answer below is only valid for finding the AssemblyVersion value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edited for better answer**

I am guessing that it is trying to get the version of the Razor Engine, not your application. So a workaround is to get this info in the controller and send it to the view through a viewbag.

In your controller add -

```
ViewBag.Version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

In your view add -

```
<h1>@ViewBag.Version</h1>
```

Comment: The executing assembly is the sameone.

Comment: Ooops, I am sorry! My fingers were faster than my mind. You are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is hidden in fact how ASP.NET handles each Page/View (Razor view). It compiles every page/view into separated dll. Its name could be as your question says:

```
App_Web_j2tdatrx.dll
```

And it is really placed inside the (please take a look)

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
```

So if you want to get the Version of "the web" assembly, you have to find it different way. Because it is not the executing one.
To get the Version in this case, do more reflection and find the library which you want to show: e.g. *Firm.Product.Web.dll*